# ¿Cómo identificar un Fragment usando el NavHostFragment?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment

En el proyecto que estoy desarrollando me he encontrado un problema, entre 2 "Fragments" estoy creando un bucle en el que uno puede redirigir al otro, **lo cual es correcto**, pero al pretender volver hacía atrás se está deshaciendo la pila de navegación, por lo que es una mala práctica ya que se redirigen el uno al otro hasta llegar al origen de uno de ellos y estoy tratando de devolver ambas a su origen directamente en caso de que el usuario retroceda.

Los bucles en cuestión son estos:

> Subjects -> SubjectFile -> TeacherFile -> SubjectFile -> TeacherFile
> -> SubjectFile -> TeacherFile
>
> Teachers -> TeacherFile -> SubjectFile -> TeacherFile -> SubjectFile
> -> TeacherFile -> SubjectFile

[image: Bucle involutario]

El "activity_launcher.xml" está diseñado así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarLayout">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/navigationHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

En el Activity tengo definido el "NavHostFragment" de la siguiente manera:

```
private NavHostFragment navHostFragment;
```

Y así lo recupero del "xml":

```
navHostFragment =
    (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigationHostFragment);
```

Y el método "onBackPressed()" está implementado así:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
  } else {
    if (navHostFragment.getParentFragment() instanceof SubjectFile) {
      Fragment subjects = new Subjects();

      getSupportFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.subjects, subjects)
          .addToBackStack(null)
          .commit();
    } else if (navHostFragment.getParentFragment() instanceof TeacherFile) {
      Fragment teachers = new Teachers();

      getSupportFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.teachers, teachers)
          .addToBackStack(null)
          .commit();
    } else {
      super.onBackPressed();
    }
  }
}
```

Mi pregunta es sencilla, no consigo recuperar el "Fragment" que se está mostrando a la hora de pulsar el botón "Back" que todo dispositivo "Android" tiene. ¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de identificarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

después de investigar y de algo de prueba y error he dado con la solución, en las acciones que redirigen de SubjectFile a TeacherFile y de TeacherFile a SubjectFile he añadido estos atributos:

```
app:popUpTo="@id/subjectFile"
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

y:

```
app:popUpTo="@id/teacherFile"
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

respectivamente, aunque esto no soluciona el problema para todas las casuísticas, por lo que en la actividad principal he tenido que hacer esto:

```
if (navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0) instanceof SubjectFile) {
    navController.popBackStack(R.id.subjects, INCLUSIVE);
} else if (navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0) instanceof TeacherFile) {
    navController.popBackStack(R.id.teachers, INCLUSIVE);
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Permitiendo que tanto si se usa el botón atrás del móvil o el del "Toolbar" retrocedan en el flujo sin crear un bucle.

Espero que esto le sirva a alguien en un futuro y si alguien detecta algo que sea incorrecto, siempre se puede editar la respuesta.